# What does somecomponent.template.dart import in AngularDart point to?

Tags: dart, angular-dart, angular-dart-routing

I am just reading the AngularDart [routing tutorial](https://webdev.dartlang.org/angular/guide/router/1#libsrcroutesdart) and came across this code snippet.

```
import 'package:angular/angular.dart';
import 'package:angular_router/angular_router.dart';

import 'route_paths.dart' as paths;
import 'crisis_list_component.template.dart' as clct;
import 'hero_list_component.template.dart' as hlct;

@Injectable()
class Routes {
  static final _crises = new RouteDefinition(
    routePath: paths.crises,
    component: clct.CrisisListComponentNgFactory,
  );

  static final _heroes = new RouteDefinition(
    routePath: paths.heroes,
    component: hlct.HeroListComponentNgFactory,
  ); ..... see routing tutorial link above.
}
```

What does

```
import 'crisis_list_component.template.dart' as clct;
import 'hero_list_component.template.dart' as hlct;
```

actually import?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Angular uses code generation to generate Dart code from Angular template syntax.

These components import the generated code. 
The code contains factory methods that are required by the router to create component instances.

If you have a

```
import 'crisis_list_component.dart';
```

then code generation will generate an additional

```
import 'crisis_list_component.template.dart' as clct;
```

which in this case is imported with an alias `clct`

Comment: Is there any documentation where i can read about this? Did not find one online :O

Comment: Not sure, Angular 5 docs are still work-in-progress as far as I know. https://webdev-dartlang-org-dev.firebaseapp.com/ I also haven't read it myself, I just closely followed the discussion.

Answer (score 0):

> The Angular compiler generates component factories behind the scenes when you build the app. To access the factory you need to import the generated component template file. Until you’ve built the app, the generated files don’t exist

Source: [Jaimeloeuf's Medium publication](https://medium.com/pslove/angulardart-pitfalls-pt-3-6154e68ca6ac)

Notice that you could find it in your project folder inside `project.dart_tools/build/generated` path.